# Cannot understand how to add new object to std::list<std::unique_ptr<classname>>

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, unique-ptr

I have strange issue with std::list of unique_ptr's.

Class slFlyingMonster is derived from class slMonster.

Following code works:

```
std::unique_ptr<slMonster> ptr(new slFlyingMonster(md));
```

But this code:

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<slMonster>> mMonsters;
mMonsters.push_back(new slFlyingMonster(md));
```

throws error:

> "Error    1   error C2664: 'void
>   std::list>,std::allocator>>>::push_back(const
>   std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : cannot convert
>   argument 1 from 'slFlyingMonster *' to
>   'std::unique_ptr> &&'"

While I understand, that something is wrong, like  std::list.push_back() is not the same as =, but I cannot figure out how to correctly add new class as unique_ptr to list. Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: Having a `std::list<std::unique_ptr>` seems like a strange thing to do. I'd assume most implementations of `std::list` already individually allocate each entry in heap-like memory. I'm talking through my hat here though. Maybe if you wanted the custom deleter functionality of `std::unique_ptr`, but you could probably implement your own helper class do get the same thing for use with `std::list`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `push_back` when you have an object of the type which your list contains, and you want to push its copy. Normally, if you don't have such an object yet (in your case, you don't), you're better off initialising a new object directly in the list — using `emplace_back` instead:

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<slMonster>> mMonsters;
mMonsters.emplace_back(new slFlyingMonster(md));
```

However, as @SebastianRedl correctly pointed out in the comments, the above has a problem of not being exception-safe. If the internal allocation of a new node inside `std::list` throws, the new `slFlyingMonster` instance would be leaked. `emplace_back` is not the correct choice when one of the arguments is an unprotected resource (such as a raw pointer owning memory).

So you actually want to construct a wrapper smart pointer and push it into the list. In C++14, you can do this with `std::make_unique`:

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<slMonster>> mMonsters;
mMonsters.push_back(std::make_unique<slFlyingMonster>(md));
```

With plain C++11, you can either implement your own `make_unique`, or explicitly create the smart pointer:

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<slMonster>> mMonsters;
mMonsters.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<slMonster>(new slFlyingMonster(md)));
```

Comment: `mMonsters.push_back( { new slFlyingMonster(md) } );` won't compile. That constructor is `explicit`.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks a lot, fixed. I was under the impression list-initialisation allowed explicit constructors. I stand corrected

Comment: This is not exception-safe. `list` has to allocate a new node before it can construct the element, and this may throw, in which case the newly allocated object is leaked.

Comment: Awesome. And here's a `make_unique` implementation for those stuck on C++11: http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/

Answer (score 7):

You may use `emplace_back`:

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<slMonster>> mMonsters;
mMonsters.emplace_back(new slFlyingMonster(md));
```

or push_back a `std::make_unique`:

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<slMonster>> mMonsters;
mMonsters.push_back(std::make_unique<slFlyingMonster>(md));
```

or `std::move` of a `std::unique_ptr`

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<slMonster>> mMonsters;
std::unique_ptr<slMonster> p(new slFlyingMonster(md));
mMonsters.push_back(std::move(p));
```

The constructor `std::unique_ptr<T>(T*)` is `explicit`, so `T*` cannot construct implicitly a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: It would be better if you also explained what the difference between `emplace_back(T&&...)` and `push_back(T&&)` is.

Comment: `push_back(make_unique...)` is the best solution. The first isn't exception-safe. The third is overly verbose unless you do more stuff between creating the object and adding it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mMonsters.emplace_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/emplace_back/) so the object is created from the argument given in parameters.